# Extending custom interface and data model

Tags: magento2, collection, model, interface

I have successfully created a custom interface.

My model: `app/code/Vendor/Samples/Model/Orders.php`

```
class Orders extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements OrdersInterface
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Samples\Model\ResourceModel\Orders');
    }

    public function getSamples()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::SAMPLES); 
    }

}
```

My interface `app/code/Vendor/Samples/Api/Data/OrdersInterface.php`

```
interface OrdersInterface
{
    const SAMPLES = 'samples';

    public function getSamples();
}
```

The return data is ids serialized like this: `["9","10","11","12","13"]`.

Now my question.

I need to unserialize this data and use this as filter in a collection from another ressource.

Basically i need to extend `$orders` with `getSamples()` method and apply custom logic like this filter each time i use it.

```
public function getOrderColors()
{
    $samples = $this->serializer->unserialize($order->getSamples());
    return $this->colorsFactory->create()->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('id', ['in' => $samples]);
}
```

I can just apply filter manually in block each time i need it, but i think it would be better to implement this logic, so i can use `$order->getSamples()` everywhere.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out i can make dependency injection in second controller like this.

File: `app/code/Vendor/Samples/Model/Orders.php`

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('Vendor\Samples\Model\ResourceModel\Orders');
}

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    \Vendor\Samples\Model\ColorsFactory $colorsFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface $serializer,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->serializer = $serializer;
    $this->colorsFactory = $colorsFactory;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $registry,
        $resource,
        $resourceCollection,
        $data
    );
}
```

And then i can create a method like this in the same file:

```
public function getSamples()
    {
        $samples = $this->serializer->unserialize($this->getData(self::SAMPLES));
        return $this->colorsFactory->create()->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('id', ['in' => $samples]);
    }
```

Now i can use `$order->getSamples()` everywhere and get expected results.

I am not sure this is best practice to accomplish this, but it works.